$H = \{(x_0, \cdots x_n) \in \mathbb{R^n} |-x_0^2+ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2=-1\}$ with Lorentzian metric is umbilical & has constant sectional curvature -1
I am making the following exercise in Riemannian Geometry:
Consider on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ the Lorentzian metric $g(x,y) = -x_0 y_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i$. Consider the hypersurface $H$ given by $H = \{-x_0^2+ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2=-1\}$. I have to show that $H$ is an umbilical hypersurface and that $H$ has constant sectional curvature -1.
I noticed that we can see $H$ as the immersion $\phi: (\mathbb{R}^n, \tilde{g}) \to (\mathbb{R^{n+1}}, g): (y_1, \cdots, y_n) \to (\sqrt{1+y_1^2 + \cdots + y_n^2, y_1, \cdots, y_n)}, \tilde{g}(X,Y) = g(d\phi(X), d\phi(Y)).$
After some calculations: $\phi(v) = (\frac{y_1v_1 + \cdots + y_n v_n}{\sqrt{1+ y_1^2+ \cdots y_n^2}}, v_1, \cdots, v_n)$. Since the ambient space has 1 dimension more than the hypersurface, $S X= \tilde{\nabla_X} N.$, since the length of $N$ =-1, with $N(p) = \sum_{i=0}^n p_i \frac{\partial}{\partial u_i}$.
$\tilde{\nabla_X} Y = XY$, so $SX = XN = \sum_{i=0}^n x_i \frac{\partial}{\partial u_i} + \sum_{i,j=0}^n p_i x_j \frac{\partial^2}{\partial u_i \partial u_j}$, where we took $X = x_i\frac{\partial}{\partial u_i}$. It doesn't seem to be of the form $f \cdot X$. Where is the mistake and how can I prove that this surface is umbilical with constant sectional curvature -1?
